# OmniSharp intellisense not recognizing new class file

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have a dotnet core console app I generated from the cli via

`dotnet new console -n EODG.VsCodeTester.Cli`

Using the [C# Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kreativ-software.csharpextensions) extension, I right click on the project folder in VSCode, and click "New C# Class".

The class/file opens just fine, but Omnisharp doesn't appear to recognize the file/class. From `Program.cs`, the class doesn't show up in the code completion, and the codelens in the new class doesn't show up.

The following is outputted from the OmniSharp log...

```
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\elrod\src\test\src\EODG.VsCodeTester.Cli\Cat.cs
```

Now, if I restart OmniSharp, it recognizes the new file just fine... but it's kind of a pain to restart omnisharp everytime I make a new class/interface or rename them. I've never seen this before, and I've been doing dotnet core development in vscode since v1.

I tried googling `OmniSharp "Could not find document for file"`... and it said `No results found for OmniSharp "Could not find document for file".`... so, that's nice.

#### Pertinent Details

- OS: Windows 10 (fresh install... like less than 2 hours old)
- VSCode version: 1.50.1
- OmniSharp version: 1.23.5
- Dotnet version: 3.1.403

I will be more than happy to provide any other details I can.

Thanks, y'all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like OmniSharp version 1.23.5 might be busted... I reverted to version 1.23.3, and things work as expected now. Possibly related to [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4174) on their git repo.

UPDATE: updating to v1.23.6 resolves this issue.

Comment: You saved my week! I had the same problem in Mac

Comment: It may resolve it in some circumstances but clearly it doesn't not solve it in all cases. I am on version 1.23.6 and I still see this problem.

Comment: @Manfred, does the problem happen when you revert the extension to 1.23.3?

Comment: @JFromTheSticks It makes no difference. I even tried the most recent beta. Meanwhile I ran a few more experiments. It appears as if this is relate to the issue that WSL2 does not generate inotify events. As a result if a Windows folder is mounted into a Linux container, this will cause a number of problems including this one. I intend to write an article in the next few weeks to explain in details including how to resolve.

Comment: Also, if someone stumbles over this question, here is another finding re omnisharp. It relies on `ps` being available in the dev container. If you use the .NET 5 SDK base image, this is not installed. You need to create a Dockerfile and in it install the missing `ps`. For an example see this Dockerfile: https://github.com/ManfredLange/issue-201121/blob/main/.devcontainer/Dockerfile

Comment: As promised I wrote an article that describes the details of the root cause of the problem I faced (dev container with WSL2 and mounted windows folder) and how to avoid it: ["Docker Desktop on WSL2: The Problem with Mixing File Systems"](https://manfredmlange.medium.com/docker-desktop-on-wsl2-the-problem-with-mixing-file-systems-a8b5dcd79b22)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in 1.23.8.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on my mac, was that in settings, search for omnisharp, then look for the option that says *Omnisharp: Use Global Mono* and set it to *always*.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow to make it work:

1. Find Assembly-CSharp.csproj.
2. Find the  field under which your
   old script names are present for compilation.
3. Add the new script name.
4. Save in Unity. Restart VS Code if required.

It should get solved.

Comment: The question has no mention of Assembly-CSharp.csproj, scripts, or Unity. Also, if you'll note in the accepted answer, this was merely a bug in that particular release of OmniSharp. Cheers!